# Java regex to make analog of _.escape

Tags: java, regex

As you know `_.escape` use this template `/[&<>"']/g`. I need to write a regex in Java which checks whether string doesn't contain any of these symbols.

*How my regex would look like?*

Comment: Well, what is `_.escape`? And how is that related to the template you gave? BTW, negating a character class can just be done with a caret (`^`)

Comment: @RohitJain I just need to check if there is no such chaarcters in my string

Comment: @RohitJain will my regex be `"^&^<^>^"^'"`?

Comment: No. It should be: `[^&<>"']`

Comment: You are better off matching what you don't want and satisfy a language conditional `if matched "[&<>"']" then bad`. Otherwise you have to match every item in the string `"\\A[^&<>\"']*\\z"`